# Inner joining 2 columns from different tables in MYSQL workbench

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry, but I'm quite newbie in SQL and PHP. Previously, I was able to easily join 2 tables columns in PHPmyadmin with the design button with out any PHP. However, I'm trying to retrieve my database with python, so I have to MYSQL workbench.

I'm trying join 2 columns on seperate tables, but I can't get it to work. Firstly, I've watched several tutorials and I really can't understand PHP and all the scripting. Secondly, I tried joining the 2 tables when in reverse engineer since it seems quite similar to PHPmyadmin, however I cannot select individual columns while in reverse engineer, even if I try to index the columns.

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oEdW.png)

I'm trying to join or make class1, class2, class3 from student table equal to classid from the class table. Is it possible at all to join the 2 tables here so it would actually show a linking between 2 specific columns? I can easily add a line but it always selects the primary key.

I appreciate any help, thanks. Alternatively, if I could get help in developing a PHP script, which also shows the linking between 2 tables, that'd also be great.

Comment: Images are not useful. Provide tables' CREATE TABLE scripts, example data as INSERT INTO and desired output for this data.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I really don't know how to use sql and provide a table script. I automatically created the tables and filled in the columns

Comment: It's bad design having numerated columns ,you should change your design to include a junction/linking table containing student and class and drop the class1,class2 and class3 columns from student.

Comment: *I really don't know how to use sql and provide a table script.* Execute `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` by any way and provide the output.